# Are variable length arrays possible with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-length

I want to make a variable length array in Javascript.

Is this possible. A quick google search for "Javascript variable length array" doesn't seem to yield anything, which would be surprising if it were possible to do this.

Should I instead have a String that I keep appending to with a separator character instead, or is there a better way to get a varible length array-like variable.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Javascript arrays are not fixed-length; you can do anything you want to at any index.

In particular, you're probably looking for the `push` method:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(2);            //Add an element
arr.push("abc");        //Not necessarily a good idea.
arr[0] = 3;             //Change an existing element
arr[2] = 100;           //Add an element
arr.pop();              //Returns 100, and removes it from the array
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array).

Comment: why is `arr.push("abc");` not a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, variable-length arrays are possible with Javascript's Array prototype. As SLaks noted, you can use `.push()` and `.pop()` to add and remove items from the end of the array respectively and the array's length property will increase and decrease by 1 respectively each time.

You can also set the value of a specific index in an array like so:

```
const arr = [];
arr[100] = 'test';
console.log(arr[100]); // 'test'
console.log(arr.length); // 101
console.log(arr[99]); // undefined
```

Every other array index besides index `100` will be `undefined`.

You can also adjust the array's length by simply setting the array's length property, like so:

```
const arr = [];
arr[100] = 'test';
arr.length = 1000;
console.log(arr[100]); // 'test'
console.log(arr.length); // 1000
```

Or...

```
const arr = [];
arr[100] = 'test';
console.log(arr.length); // 101
arr.length -= 10;
console.log(arr.length); // 91
console.log(arr[100]); // undefined
```

The maximum value that an array's length property can be is 4,294,967,295. Interestingly though, you can set values of an array at indices larger than 4,294,967,295:

```
const arr1 = [];
const arr2 = [];
arr1[4294967294] = 'wow';
arr2[4294967295] = 'ok?';
console.log(arr1[4294967294]); // 'wow'
console.log(arr1.length); // 4294967295
console.log(arr2[4294967295]); // 'ok?'
console.log(arr2.length); // 0
```

If you try to set length a number larger than 4,294,967,295 it will throw a RangeError:

```
const arr = [];
arr.length = 4294967296;
console.log(arr.length); // RangeError: Invalid array length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Array()` constructor.

```
const desiredLength = 5; // could be dynamically generated

const list = new Array(desiredLength); // will be length 5
```

---

One caveat is that you will be unable to map the initial elements by using `Array(n).map()`. Instead, you can use `Array.from()` ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

```
const desiredLength = 5; // could be dynamically generated

const passkeys = Array.from(Array(desiredLength), () => {
    return Math.random().toString(32).substring(2, 10);
});
```